# Why $\rho(t)^{-1}(H-\frac{\partial}{\partial h_{\rho^{\vee}}}) \rho(t) = H - \frac{1}{2}(\rho^{\vee}, \rho^{\vee})$?

Tags: representation-theory

I am reading the [paper](http://xxx.tau.ac.il/abs/1308.5451). On page 17, line 15, why $$ \rho(t)^{-1}(H-\frac{\partial}{\partial h_{\rho^{\vee}}}) \rho(t) = H - \frac{1}{2}(\rho^{\vee}, \rho^{\vee}) $$? Here $$ H = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i\in I}  (\frac{\partial}{\partial h_i})^2 + \sum_{i\in I} \alpha_{i}(t), $$ 
$\alpha_i$ are simple roots, $h_i \in \mathfrak{h}$ are standard coordinates of $\mathfrak{h}$, $h_{\rho^{\vee}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha \in R^+} h_{\alpha}$, $\rho=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha \in R^+} \alpha $.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\rho(t)^{-1} H \rho(t) = H$. By definition,
\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial}{\partial h_{\rho^{\vee}}} \rho(t) \\
& = \frac{d}{da}|_{a=0} \rho(t e^{a h_{\rho^{\vee}}}) \\
& = \frac{d}{da}|_{a=0} \rho(t) \rho(e^{a h_{\rho^{\vee}}}) \\
& = \rho(t) \frac{d}{da}|_{a=0}  e^{<\rho, a h_{\rho^{\vee}}>} \\
& = \rho(t) \frac{d}{da}|_{a=0}  e^{(\rho^{\vee}, a \rho^{\vee})} \\
& = \rho(t) \frac{d}{da}|_{a=0}  e^{a(\rho^{\vee}, \rho^{\vee})} \\
& = \rho(t) (\rho^{\vee}, \rho^{\vee}).
\end{align}

Therefore 
$$ 
\rho(t)^{-1}(H-\frac{\partial}{\partial h_{\rho^{\vee}}}) \rho(t) = H - (\rho^{\vee}, \rho^{\vee}).
$$

It is slightly different from the conclusion in the paper. It seems that usually $h_{\rho^{\vee}} = \rho$. But in the paper, $h_{\rho^{\vee}} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha \in R^+} h_{\alpha} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha \in R^{+}} \alpha^{\vee} = \rho^{\vee}$.